# how to create function in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

how to create function in PostgreSQL am using below code

```
create table sample(id int primary key)
create table sample2(id int primary key)


create view sampleall
As 
select id from sample
union
select id from sample2
```

while creating below function for above tables

```
Create FUNCTION CheckFunction (ID INT)
RETURNS BIT AS
$$
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sampleall WHERE id = @ID)
    BEGIN

        RETURN 1
    END




    RETURN 0

END
  $$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TABLE sample3 (ID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CHK_ID CHECK (dbo.CheckFunction(ID) = 1))
```

and getting below error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"
LINE 8:     BEGIN
            ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "BEGIN"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 132
```

please help to solve the issue

Comment: Add a `THEN`...

Answer (score 2):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) an `IF` requires a `THEN`. Additionally, parameters cannot be prefixed with a `@`. To avoid a name clash between a parameter name and a column name you should use a different name for the parameter. A common approach is to prefix parameters with `p_`

However your function is needlessly complex and can be simplified substantially if you return a proper `boolean` rather than a bit:

```
Create FUNCTION check_function (p_ID INT)
RETURNS boolean AS
$$
  select exists (SELECT 1 FROM sampleall WHERE id = p_id);
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Your check constraint can then  be simplified to:

```
CREATE TABLE sample3 (ID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CHK_ID CHECK (check_Function(ID));
```